# Access an instance dictionary from a string at runtime?

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
[Serializable]
public class DOCharStats
{
    public int Stamina { get; set; }
    public int maxStamina { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class DOMapStats
{
    public int xlocation { get; set; }
    public int ylocation { get; set; }
}
//Name of char and stats

public static Dictionary<string, DOCharStats> dCharStats = new Dictionary<string, DOCharStats>();
public static Dictionary<string, DOMapStats> dMapStats = new Dictionary<string, DOMapStats>();

//Name of container and dict.
public static Dictionary<string, object> dContainer = new Dictionary<string, object>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DOCharStats newStats = new DOCharStats();

    dCharStats.Add("MC", newStats);
    Console.WriteLine(dCharStats["MC"].Stamina);
    Console.WriteLine(dCharStats["MC"].maxStamina);


    newStats.Stamina = 5;
    newStats.maxStamina = 10;
    Console.WriteLine(dCharStats["MC"].Stamina);
    Console.WriteLine(dCharStats["MC"].maxStamina);

    DOMapStats mapstats = new DOMapStats();
    mapstats.xlocation = 20;
    mapstats.ylocation = 40;
    dMapStats.Add("MC", mapstats);


    //How to access dCharStats(dictionary variant) from a string?
    dContainer.Add("_dCharStats",dCharStats);
    dContainer.Add("_dMapStats", dMapStats);
}
```

`dCharStats` and `dMapStats` will be modified by other methods while the program is running.

I would like to access & modify `dCharStats` or `dMapStats` based on a string. I have tried doing this via `dContainer`, but I am unable to cast `dCharStats(object)` to `dCharStats(Dictionary<String,DOCharStats>)` in a generic fashion.

Is there a way to access an instance dictionary (dCharStats) from a string at runtime?

Comment: what do you mean by  i am unable to cast to Dictionary in a generic fashion? cant you just do `(Dictionary<string, DOCharStats>)dContainer["_dCharStats"]` ?

Comment: here is a tutorial on how to create and access Dictionary<> http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson20

Comment: The issue here is specifying DOCharStats as the type. I have several different kinds of Data Object classes. It would require writing code for every new DO class.

Answer (score 0):

```
        dContainer.Add(_dCharStats, dCharStats);
        dContainer.Add("_dMapStats", dMapStats);
        object secondObj = (object)dCharStats;

        dynamic someObj = dContainer[_dCharStats];

        foreach (dynamic blah in someObj)
        {
            dynamic internalObj = blah.Value;
            int somevalue = internalObj.GetType().GetProperty("Stamina").GetValue(internalObj, null);
            internalObj.GetType().GetProperty("Stamina").SetValue(internalObj, 8080, null);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("After:"+dCharStats["MC"].Stamina);
        Console.WriteLine("After:" + dCharStats["MC"].maxStamina);
```

An hour or two after posting this, it looks like using dynamic variables resolves my issue.